# Add SOAPHeader to each request

Tags: c#, wcf, soapheader

I'm very new about this topic, so I'm sorry if my problem explanation will be not very clear.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 c#, and I'm creating a sw that has to connect to a server to read some data.

I add a WFC Web service using the integrated tool in VS and it creates a connected service that inhertis from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase and XXXProxy classes.

To connect to the server I need the credentials and to add a SOAPHeader to the messages.

How can I add this SOAPHeader?

I have the corresponding java code and for each request a SOAPHeader is created with SOAPHeaderElement.

Can anyone give me an help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try the message inspector, on the client side, intercept SOAP messages by implementing the [`IClientMessageInspector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface. On the server side, intercept SOAP messages by implementing the [`IDispatchMessageInspector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface.

You can also use [`OperationContextScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to create new contexts in client applications to add custom headers to outgoing messages.

These are some usefull links:
[Adding SOAP Header to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835091/adding-soap-header-to-request)

 [Adding Http Header in an existing WCF SOAP Service is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512493/adding-http-header-in-an-existing-wcf-soap-service-is-not-working)

 [How to add custom soap headers in wcf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976217/how-to-add-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf)